# Inconsistent results from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Friends - I'm using BeautifulSoup to try to pull a particular link from each of a series of 'index' pages on the SEC web site. I've tried a number of different ways of doing it, and they all sorta work, but none seem to work *consistently*. I can't figure out why I would get different results when I run the program multiple times, but I do. If I feed in 12 'index' pages, I'll find the link I'm looking for, say, 6 times, then 11 times, then 9 times. Even if I'm not finding all 12 links, shouldn't I at least get the same number correct every time?

Anyway, here is my code:

```
def getxsd(indexurl):
    index_page = requests.get(indexurl)
    index_text = index_page.text
    index_soup = BeautifulSoup(index_text, 'lxml')
    links = index_soup.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        if '.xsd' in link.text:
            print(link)
```

Then I'll feed in my list of index pages

```
for filing in filings:
   getxsd(filing)
```

Seems pretty straightforward. But, as I said, I seldom get the same results twice. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Or, alternatively, point me to a better way of doing what I want?

For completeness, here is the list of urls that I'm actually feeding into the getxsd function:

> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1138724/000101489721000009/0001014897-21-000009-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1783875/000156459021017873/0001564590-21-017873-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/924515/000165495421003915/0001654954-21-003915-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1549145/000149315221008113/0001493152-21-008113-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/89140/000110465921047154/0001104659-21-047154-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/845819/000151597121000031/0001515971-21-000031-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1794717/000121390021020418/0001213900-21-020418-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/744825/000074482521000030/0000744825-21-000030-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1290658/000168316821001249/0001683168-21-001249-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1160798/000121390021020286/0001213900-21-020286-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1642159/000149315221008047/0001493152-21-008047-index.htm
> https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1748621/000121390021020254/0001213900-21-020254-index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was a pretty stupid problem. But just in case anyone else ever has the same sort of issue and comes looking here:
I was getting a '403 Client Error' when I tried to access some of the index pages. I don't know if this was because I was trying to access too many per second or what, but sometimes it would happen, sometimes it wouldn't.
I added `index_page.raise_for_status()` below the `index_page = requests.get(indexurl)` in my original function and that flagged all of the pages I was having trouble with. I've rigged it so that the function waits a couple of seconds when there's a bad status and then tries again, which seems to work pretty well. Haven't finalized the solution, but at least I've identified the issue.